# django 2.1.4 migration fails with "DETAIL: Key columns "xxx" and "yyy" are of incompatible types: integer and character varying"

Tags: django

I'm trying to upgrade a django 1.11 based service to latest django 2.1.4.
When running migrations ( during unit testing ) I now get the following error in an existing migration of my django application that did not happen before upgrade to latest django version !?

`DETAIL:  Key columns "xxx" and "yyy" are of incompatible types: integer and character varying`.

**How can such an existing django migration be fixed when upgrading to latest django version ?**

The models (snippet) changed from

```
class Aaa(models.model):
    # id based on default primary key => integer based

class Bbb(models.model):
    # id based on default primary key => integer based
    aaa = models.ForeignKey(Aaa, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

to

```
class Aaa(models.model):
    id = models.CharField(primary_key=True, max_length=36, editable=False)

class Bbb(models.model):
    id = models.CharField(primary_key=True, max_length=36, editable=False)
    aaa = models.ForeignKey(Aaa, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

The callstack of the exception during the migration (from scratch) when setting up the unit-test environment looks like the following :

```
foo_aaa__________ ERROR at setup of ViewTests.test_aaa ___________

self = <django.db.backends.utils.CursorWrapper object at 0x7fa7ac64a240>
sql = 'ALTER TABLE "foo_aaa" ALTER COLUMN "id" TYPE varchar(36) USING "id"::varchar(36)'
params = []
ignored_wrapper_args = (False, {'connection': <django.db.backends.postgresql.base.DatabaseWrapper object at 0x7fa7b5235780>, 'cursor': <django.db.backends.utils.CursorWrapper object at 0x7fa7ac64a240>})

    def _execute(self, sql, params, *ignored_wrapper_args):
        self.db.validate_no_broken_transaction()
        with self.db.wrap_database_errors:
            if params is None:
                return self.cursor.execute(sql)
            else:
>               return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
E               psycopg2.ProgrammingError: foreign key constraint "foo_bbb_aaa_id_1e82a2eb_fk_foo" cannot be implemented
E               DETAIL:  Key columns "aaa_id" and "id" are of incompatible types: integer and character varying.

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py:85: ProgrammingError

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

request = <SubRequest '_django_setup_unittest' for <TestCaseFunction 'test_aaa'>>
django_db_blocker = <pytest_django.plugin._DatabaseBlocker object at 0x7fa7b83b9ba8>

    @pytest.fixture(autouse=True, scope="class")
    def _django_setup_unittest(request, django_db_blocker):
        """Setup a django unittest, internal to pytest-django."""
        if django_settings_is_configured() and is_django_unittest(request):
            request.getfixturevalue("django_test_environment")
>           request.getfixturevalue("django_db_setup")

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pytest_django/plugin.py:486: 
_ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ 
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/six.py:692: in reraise
    raise value.with_traceback(tb)
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pytest_django/fixtures.py:110: in django_db_setup
    **setup_databases_args
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/test/utils.py:174: in setup_databases
    serialize=connection.settings_dict.get('TEST', {}).get('SERIALIZE', True),
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/creation.py:68: in create_test_db
    run_syncdb=True,
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py:148: in call_command
    return command.execute(*args, **defaults)
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py:353: in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py:83: in wrapped
    res = handle_func(*args, **kwargs)
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/migrate.py:203: in handle
    fake_initial=fake_initial,
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/migrations/executor.py:117: in migrate
    state = self._migrate_all_forwards(state, plan, full_plan, fake=fake, fake_initial=fake_initial)
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/migrations/executor.py:147: in _migrate_all_forwards
    state = self.apply_migration(state, migration, fake=fake, fake_initial=fake_initial)
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/migrations/executor.py:244: in apply_migration
    state = migration.apply(state, schema_editor)
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/migrations/migration.py:124: in apply
    operation.database_forwards(self.app_label, schema_editor, old_state, project_state)
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/migrations/operations/fields.py:216: in database_forwards
    schema_editor.alter_field(from_model, from_field, to_field)
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/schema.py:523: in alter_field
    old_db_params, new_db_params, strict)
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/postgresql/schema.py:122: in _alter_field
    new_db_params, strict,
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/schema.py:663: in _alter_field
    params,
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/schema.py:133: in execute
    cursor.execute(sql, params)
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py:68: in execute
    return self._execute_with_wrappers(sql, params, many=False, executor=self._execute)
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py:77: in _execute_with_wrappers
    return executor(sql, params, many, context)
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py:85: in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/utils.py:89: in __exit__
    raise dj_exc_value.with_traceback(traceback) from exc_value
_ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ 

self = <django.db.backends.utils.CursorWrapper object at 0x7fa7ac64a240>
sql = 'ALTER TABLE "foo_aaa" ALTER COLUMN "id" TYPE varchar(36) USING "id"::varchar(36)'
params = []
ignored_wrapper_args = (False, {'connection': <django.db.backends.postgresql.base.DatabaseWrapper object at 0x7fa7b5235780>, 'cursor': <django.db.backends.utils.CursorWrapper object at 0x7fa7ac64a240>})

    def _execute(self, sql, params, *ignored_wrapper_args):
        self.db.validate_no_broken_transaction()
        with self.db.wrap_database_errors:
            if params is None:
                return self.cursor.execute(sql)
            else:
>               return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
E               django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: foreign key constraint "foo_bbb_aaa_id_1e82a2eb_fk_foo" cannot be implemented
E               DETAIL:  Key columns "aaa_id" and "id" are of incompatible types: integer and character varying.

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py:85: ProgrammingError
_____ ERROR at setup of ViewTests.test_bar ______

self = <django.db.backends.utils.CursorWrapper object at 0x7fa7ac64a240>
sql = 'ALTER TABLE "foo_aaa" ALTER COLUMN "id" TYPE varchar(36) USING "id"::varchar(36)'
params = []
ignored_wrapper_args = (False, {'connection': <django.db.backends.postgresql.base.DatabaseWrapper object at 0x7fa7b5235780>, 'cursor': <django.db.backends.utils.CursorWrapper object at 0x7fa7ac64a240>})

    def _execute(self, sql, params, *ignored_wrapper_args):
        self.db.validate_no_broken_transaction()
        with self.db.wrap_database_errors:
            if params is None:
                return self.cursor.execute(sql)
            else:
>               return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
E               psycopg2.ProgrammingError: foreign key constraint "foo_bbb_aaa_id_1e82a2eb_fk_foo" cannot be implemented
E               DETAIL:  Key columns "aaa_id" and "id" are of incompatible types: integer and character varying.

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py:85: ProgrammingError

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

tp = <class 'django.db.utils.ProgrammingError'>, value = None, tb = None

    def reraise(tp, value, tb=None):
        try:
            if value is None:
                value = tp()
            if value.__traceback__ is not tb:
>               raise value.with_traceback(tb)

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/six.py:692: 
_ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ 
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pytest_django/plugin.py:486: in _django_setup_unittest
    request.getfixturevalue("django_db_setup")
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/six.py:692: in reraise
    raise value.with_traceback(tb)
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pytest_django/fixtures.py:110: in django_db_setup
    **setup_databases_args
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/test/utils.py:174: in setup_databases
    serialize=connection.settings_dict.get('TEST', {}).get('SERIALIZE', True),
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/creation.py:68: in create_test_db
    run_syncdb=True,
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py:148: in call_command
    return command.execute(*args, **defaults)
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py:353: in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py:83: in wrapped
    res = handle_func(*args, **kwargs)
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/migrate.py:203: in handle
    fake_initial=fake_initial,
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/migrations/executor.py:117: in migrate
    state = self._migrate_all_forwards(state, plan, full_plan, fake=fake, fake_initial=fake_initial)
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/migrations/executor.py:147: in _migrate_all_forwards
    state = self.apply_migration(state, migration, fake=fake, fake_initial=fake_initial)
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/migrations/executor.py:244: in apply_migration
    state = migration.apply(state, schema_editor)
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/migrations/migration.py:124: in apply
    operation.database_forwards(self.app_label, schema_editor, old_state, project_state)
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/migrations/operations/fields.py:216: in database_forwards
    schema_editor.alter_field(from_model, from_field, to_field)
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/schema.py:523: in alter_field
    old_db_params, new_db_params, strict)
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/postgresql/schema.py:122: in _alter_field
    new_db_params, strict,
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/schema.py:663: in _alter_field
    params,
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/schema.py:133: in execute
    cursor.execute(sql, params)
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py:68: in execute
    return self._execute_with_wrappers(sql, params, many=False, executor=self._execute)
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py:77: in _execute_with_wrappers
    return executor(sql, params, many, context)
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py:85: in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/utils.py:89: in __exit__
    raise dj_exc_value.with_traceback(traceback) from exc_value
_ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ 

self = <django.db.backends.utils.CursorWrapper object at 0x7fa7ac64a240>
sql = 'ALTER TABLE "foo_aaa" ALTER COLUMN "id" TYPE varchar(36) USING "id"::varchar(36)'
params = []
ignored_wrapper_args = (False, {'connection': <django.db.backends.postgresql.base.DatabaseWrapper object at 0x7fa7b5235780>, 'cursor': <django.db.backends.utils.CursorWrapper object at 0x7fa7ac64a240>})

    def _execute(self, sql, params, *ignored_wrapper_args):
        self.db.validate_no_broken_transaction()
        with self.db.wrap_database_errors:
            if params is None:
                return self.cursor.execute(sql)
            else:
>               return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
E               django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: foreign key constraint "foo_bbb_aaa_id_1e82a2eb_fk_foo" cannot be implemented
E               DETAIL:  Key columns "aaa_id" and "id" are of incompatible types: integer and character varying.

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py:85: ProgrammingError
```

Comment: maybe error is `id` is integer, but you define in `AAA` `id = models.CharField`. Why you want id is char field?

Comment: `AAA` will be integer because in `Bbb` you define FK. It will auto create fk_id type = integer

Comment: the code/model is working as expected using older django v1.11 !
Using pimary-key field "id" of type char works as expected.

Comment: You could try generating a similar migration using Django 2.1, to see whether the migration file produced is different. Or perhaps you can squash your migrations so that the migration isn’t necessary when running your test suite.

Comment: Using django 2.1.4 I created two dummy models that use the same field-type and changes of field-types and created migrations for them.
The generated migration-code in the two new migration-py files looks exactly like the former working migration in my application that now fails with the strange error !?

Comment: Simple attempt to use auto-generated squashed migration fails with the same error - django was just generated the same migration steps ( this time just in one file ) !?
Maybe I have to make django pretend that it should generate initial migration, take to content of that migration and use it in the "squashed" migration instead...

Answer (score 0):

I fixed the problem by manually editing the formerly working migrations to eliminate the change of the primary-key field type in the first place. I.e. my initial migration now already contains the model spec that was formerly changed in a later migration. In the later migration I removed the editing completely.